# Save to user database from a Json response in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I successfully implement a payment gateway on my Laravel Application

But I get this response from the payment

```
    public function handleGatewayCallback()
    {
        $paymentDetails = Payant::getPaymentData();
        dd($paymentDetails);
    }
```

[image]

What I am trying to is to save some of the response to the user database, but I am unable to achieve  this. I tried doing it this way

```
   public function handleGatewayCallback(Request $request)
    {
        $paymentDetails = Payant::getPaymentData();
      //  dd($paymentDetails);
        $user = User::find(Auth::id());
        $user->sub_paid_at = $request->paid_at;
        $user->role = $request->planObject['name'];
        $user->save();
    }
```

It returned this error

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'sub_paid_at' cannot be null (SQL: update `users` set `sub_paid_at` = ?, `users`.`updated_at` = 2019-12-14 07:27:45 where `id` = 3)

### UPDATE

This is my user database Schema

```
   public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->enum('role', ['subscriber', 'admin', 'basic', 'couple', 'family'])->default('subscriber');
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('avatar')->nullable();
            $table->integer('no_of_logins')->default(0);
            $table->date('sub_paid_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('session_id')->nullable();
            $table->string('password')->nullable();
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();

        });
    }
```

I want to be able to update user role from the response, so I tried this

```
  $user->role = $request->plan_object['name'];
```

But it returned error

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'role' cannot be null (SQL: update `users` set `role` = ?, `sub_paid_at` = 1970-01-01 00:00:00, `users`.`updated_at` = 2019-12-14 08:40:46 where `id` = 3)

Comment: please put code of your output not image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fix my question

```
 $user = User::find(Auth::id());
$user->sub_paid_at = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($paymentDetails['data']['paidAt']));
$user->role = $paymentDetails['data']['plan_object']['name'];
 $user->save();
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your variable name from `paid_at` to `paidAt`

```
    $user->sub_paid_at = $request->paidAt;
```

But better you change format

```
   $user->sub_paid_at = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($request->paidAt));
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But I tried to do  `$user->role = $request->name;. It returned the same error. Is there anything I am doing wrong.